# How to easily convert a BufferedReader to a String?

Tags: java, json

```
@POST
@Path("/getphotos")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String getPhotos() throws IOException{
    // DataInputStream rd = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")
    );
    String line = null;
    String message = new String();
    final StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(2048);
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        // buffer.append(line);
        message += line;
    }
    System.out.println(message);
    JsonObject json = new JsonObject(message);
    return message;
}
```

The code above is for my servlet. Its purpose is to get a stream, make a a Json file from it, and then send the Json to the client back.
But in order to make Json, I have to read `BufferedReader` object `rd` using a "while" loop. However I'd like to convert `rd` to string in as few lines of code as possible. How do I do that?

Comment: Hard to see what your objection to three extra lines of code could be.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

From Java 8:

```
rd.lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Comment: Excellent! People should give more value to solutions that don't require adding big, fat libraries to one's projects.

Comment: By the way, I had to do `Collectors.joining("\n")` to add a trailing newline character to each line.

Comment: `Call requires API level 24 (current min is xx): java.io.BufferedReader#lines`

Comment: VERY IMPORTANT to do the Collectors.joining("\n"). this answer is so wrong! i hope others dont miss it as i did. 
also, very important, what if the request body is using other escape characters, like `\r`? not sure. so i would prefer the IOUtils library instead

Comment: `\r` will actually be converted to `\n` and this might be causing bugs in some cases (in my case it did, cause the outcome is being used in hmac and the hash that i m creating doesnt match the one that i received)

Answer (score 61):

I suggest using commons IO library - then it is a simple 1 liner:

```
String message = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(rd);
```

of course, be aware that using this mechanism, a denial of service attack could be made, by sending a never ending stream of data that will fill up your server memory.

Comment: Java totally needs more one-liners

Comment: I would use this if commons-io had been updated in the last 3 years :(

Answer (score 28):

I found myself doing this today.  Did not want to bring in IOUtils, so I went with this:

```
String response = new String();
for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; response += line);
```

Comment: Short and sweet.

Answer (score 2):

Use a variable as String like this:

```
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
String line = "";
while((line = rd.readLine()) != null){

}
```

Comment: The last line of the buffer won't be added to the String if it doesn't end with '\n'

Comment: However this is exactly the same as the code that was posted, only worse.

Answer (score 2):

Since Java 10, you can do the following:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream(), "UTF-8").transferTo(writer);
System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

Note that this approach has the advantage of properly handling escape characters, properly buffering the characters for greater efficiency, using a `StringBuffer` to construct the string at the end, and not bringing in external libraries.

Since Java 9, you can convert directly from an `InputStream` to a `StringWriter` like this:

```
 StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
 request.getInputStream().transferTo(writer);
 System.out.println(writer.toString());
```