# Accessing JSON array node inside an object

Tags: java, arrays, json, tags

I've been having trouble with accessing a JSON array node inside another object.

The JSON file I'm trying to read basically looks like this:

```
[
{
  "dependencies": [ "data"
  ]
}
]
```

I've got to the point where I'm unable to access the tag using the code I have and I've got no idea how.

I'm using the JSON library from http://www.json.org/java/

The full code that I've used in this example is here:

```
    List depList;

    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();

    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    JdomParser jp = new JdomParser();
    JsonRootNode js = jp.parse(rd);

    if(js.getArrayNode(0).get(0).getArrayNode("dependencies").size() > 0){
        depList = js.getArrayNode(0).get(0).getArrayNode("dependencies");
        is.close();
        return depList;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
```

The specific line that I'm using is this one: `js.getArrayNode(0).get(0).getArrayNode("dependencies")`

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONArray outArray = new JSONArray(json);
JSONObject outObject = outArray.getJSONObject(0);
JSONArray inArray = outObject.getJSONArray("dependencies");
String data = inArray.getString(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some sample code that should help you.  This prints out "data".

```
package com.sandbox;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Sandbox {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        String input = "[\n" +
                "{\n" +
                "  \"dependencies\": [ \"data\"\n" +
                "  ]\n" +
                "}\n" +
                "]";

        JSONArray start = new JSONArray(input);
        JSONObject jsonObject = start.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONArray dependencies = jsonObject.getJSONArray("dependencies");
        String data = dependencies.getString(0);
        System.out.println(data);
    }

}
```

Here's my maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I'm downloading the JSON data from a `BufferedReader`, and tried using the `toString()` method on the reader variable then used that as the `input` variable. When I tried that I got an error stating that `A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think your problem is that you're using `toString` on a `BufferedReader` when you shouldn't be.  Print out the results of the `toString` and let me know what they are.  This should help you fix your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040504/how-to-converting-bufferedreader-to-string-at-once

Comment: I figured that that would be my problem. The output is `java.io.BufferedReader@5be7ef2c`

Comment: @JamEngulfer221 OK, see the SO post I linked to to fix your issue.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to use that class/method as it appears to not exist.

Comment: @JamEngulfer221 You need to add IOUtils to your classpath to use it.  If you want to do this in pure java look at this code: http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-bufferedreader-readline-string-examples