# How to get response from API(Server) in android

Tags: android, json, httpurlconnection

I have designed a sign up form which is sending JSON data on the server. I want to know how to process or access the server response in Android so that in case of repetition of an entry, I can display that an `id` already exists.

Comment: use retrofit for posting data to the server

Comment: I have posted data successfully to the server using httpurlconnection. Now i want to handle server response in case of registered mobile number or email id used to sign up

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20976385/754783) answer. it's already been questioned and answered.