# Read HTTP response header and body from one HTTP request in java

Tags: java, http, network-programming

In my program I need to send a HTTP request and read the HTTP response body and headers.

So I added those examples together as follows;

```
URL obj = new URL("http://localhost:8080/SpringSecurity/admin");
URLConnection conn = obj.openConnection();

//get all headers
Map<String, List<String>> map = conn.getHeaderFields();
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " ,Value : " + entry.getValue());
}        
ByteArrayOutputStream output = (ByteArrayOutputStream) conn.getOutputStream();        

byte[] input = output.toByteArray();         
System.out.println(input.length);
```

It prints the headers but it doesn't print the length of byte array `input`.

Can someone explain why this is happening and example of reading both HTTP response headers and body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done wrong in this one is opening an output stream that writes to the connection using `conn.getOutputStream()`. So I opened an input stream that reads from the connection using `conn.getInputStream()`.

So the corrected form of code is;

```
URL obj = new URL("http://localhost:8080/SpringSecurity/admin");          
URLConnection conn = obj.openConnection();

//get all response headers
Map<String, List<String>> map = conn.getHeaderFields();
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " ,Value : " + entry.getValue());
}

//get response body
InputStream output = conn.getInputStream();
Scanner s = new Scanner(output).useDelimiter("\\A");
String result = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: The code is not correct. You should not use `getInputStream()` and `getHeaderFields()`  together becase you will get incomplete data. The reason for that is `getHeaderFields` internally calls `getInputStream` ( http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java#2092 ). For more details see comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20976385/4682359