# Android Java: Get Response Body from HttpUrlConnection

Tags: java, android, character-encoding, httpurlconnection, httpresponse

I have an `HttpUrlConnection` and I can get response `Headers` from it like below:

[How to read full response from HttpURLConnection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20976013/how-to-read-full-response-from-httpurlconnection)

But I've tried many ways to get the response `Body` without success. For example:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
sb = new StringBuilder();
String output;
while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
sb.append(output);
return sb.toString();
```

Or

```
Other ways... (With UTF-8 Encoding and ...)
```

The problem is that the result contains invalid character. For instance if the response is an image, I cannot have the correct image and it contains invalid characters:

The **Correct** Image:

```
‰PNG


IHDR  è  £   ؟£?b       pHYs     ڑœ  
OiCCPPhotoshop ICC profile  xع‌SgTSé=÷قôBKˆ€”KoR RB‹€‘&*!   Jˆ!،ظQءEEب ˆژژ€ŒQ,ٹ
```

The **Incorrect** Image: (What I've got from response body)

```
<>�t:�t�R���k�ҥ��c�ƍZ�n�6mڤW^y���
6���/׼y�1���B��������ƍ;
�˖-�'�|�+V��h�Z�e�3����%%%)--M�����/��   � �}h��m6�JKK��Oh�����㏽�QWW���T%&&*++��s���ph���III�<�%%%)<<�#�),,L+V����ý����TII����x�b=��*--�Z���M�2�l�nt�ө��|�{�z��ǵe���<??_�g�VVV���={��?^�|��wF����<͟?_���gmP:  �:� �C�|���t�R���r:�z������{}���B���k���o�$
>\���^�?!!Ak׮լY�$�j�%Wq�ݮu��i���r:�
```

How can I get the response body from `HttpUrlConnection` **WITHOUT** any changes with correct characters (formatting, encoding and ...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the body is a PNG image, it will be binary data, and you're expected to use the inputstream, not a reader.

UPDATE:

Example: to store the image in file "myimage.png":

```
try (InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("myimage.png")) {
    byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
    int n;
    while ((n = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you please provide me a code? I can't understand what you've mentioned.

Comment: @JohnCroneh here is an example