# How do I access the API error message property using Java exception?

Tags: java, api, exception, message

On api.sap.com, there are useable trial APIs.
And I tried one of the POST Request samples.
On this link [SAP API Trial](https://api.sap.com/api/ECEmployeeCentralPayroll/tryout), I've used the Java Code Snippet they show on my locally created Java API.

On this Case, I am expecting an error like how it is shown when I run the trial on the link.
[image]

As the code snippet for java on the link shows, it goes through the Catch part, catching the exception.
What I want to do is access the "error.message.value" property of the response given to me.
I tried using exception.getMessage(), or most of the options under the exception class, but it does not give me the expected content of the "value" property.
I have also tried the suggestion on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20976013/how-to-read-full-response-from-httpurlconnection) on how to read the full response. but it does not show what i want.

Is there a way to access it?

[edit]attaching the exception part of the code and the results I got.
[image]

Comment: Fix the case of your title.

Comment: The SAP API trial link requires a login. Please include the code you’re using in the question text.