# Can't save results of BufferedReader.readLine() to String

Tags: java, android

I can log the result of `BufferedReader.readLine()` with `Log.e("debug", e.getMessage())`, but can't assign the result to a `String`. Why is that?

```
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            //Connecting
            Log.i(debugString, "Attempting to connect to server");
            socket = new Socket(hostname, portnumber);
            Log.i(debugString, "Connection established!");

            //receive message from server
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            Log.e(debugString, br.readLine());  // This works, but really...
            String s = br.readLine(); // ...this is how I *want* to save it.
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(debugString, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: I hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040504/how-to-easily-convert-a-bufferedreader-to-a-string

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown any code where you try to display the result from the `readLine()` call. If you want the result to display in your app, you have to display the result in your app. You assign the value read to a variable `s` (not a good name, btw), then silently drop the reference, thus losing the returned value before you ever display it.

Also, you need to **handle** the `IOException`, not merely log it, and you should close your I/O connections before you leave the subroutine.

Comment: I t would be helpful if you would write what you mean, I am actually new to this..

Comment: You assigned a value to `s`, then did nothing with `s`. Displaying a value requires code to display it. That means to apply the text value to a display widget like a `TextView`. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Comment: Exceptions: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html

Comment: I'm not new in the level of not knowing what textview is, I mean I am new to networking in my programs.. When I try to toast the 's' it just shows me a null value..

Comment: Your code example shows no attempt to display `s`. This has nothing to do with networking.

Comment: M8, it's obvoius that I toasted it after the thread is over, but my problem is that the variable s just stays null because it doesn't get any value from br.readLine()

Comment: It is far from obvious that you toasted it after the thread is over, especially because `s` is local to a block that is local to a method that is local to the thread. It is not even possible to toast `s` outside the thread.

Comment: @LewBloch is right about the variable name. I've been doing this a long time and I've found the more carefully and intelligently I pick names for everything in the code, from the app name, object names, method names, variable names -- *everything*, the more sensibly I do that, the more readable and self-evident the code is and it helps the program write itself, because many times you go "why would I do *that* with a *this*? Clearly *this* is a sub-aspect of a *that*, etc...

Comment: @EldarAzulay Not obvious AT ALL what you are really thinking. And it was a pretty sloppy, poorly thought out and edited post to begin with, IMO. Who knows what you really had in mind for s. The fact that you're even asking the question, which seems pretty basic means, maybe just be a bit more humble about it.

Comment: @clearlight well, you know the 's' was just for example, I changed it's name later but I just wanted to create a temporary variable to show you how I want to save it.. Well now I managed to save it because I forgot that when I tried to write it to log I used the readLine() command and that was what emptied the incoming string, so I couldn't get it anyway.

Comment: OK, but we don't know. I get in a rush too, but it *really* helps to post carefully, format well, prune code and comments that aren't needed, name things well, show the code you're using rather than something modified at the last minute to reduce errors and not waste people's time, etc... And try to catch and reduce ambiguities. Try to consider how someone who doesn't know what you're doing in infinite detail might perceive it. You didn't show too much code, and renaming it was okay, but it's weird when you mix pseudo/demo code/names in with real code. We don't have the context.

Comment: @LewBloch I didn't mean it would be local, I made it local just for here to tell you that I want to save it to string, but anyway, the only way I could save the br.readLine() value to a string was to a static variable and it worked. I resolved my problem.

Comment: @clearlight you are right, but actually my problem here was pretty simple, I mean you didn't have much to think when you see that I used twice the br.readLine(), it was dumb of me and I don't know how I didn't notice it..

Comment: @EldarAzulay you didn't do anything horrible in any aspect of this. We've all been thrown by 'obvious' bugs. No biggy really. Just take whatever is valuable to you in this and forget the rest :-)