# Why i cant get request body from HttpServeletRequest

Tags: json, servlets, request

Im sending a postman POST request same as this. What i want is get this request body into a String variable.

```
 {
   "RechargeRequest":{
      "RechargeSerialNo":"2645",
      "RechargeChannelID":"3",
      "RechargeObj":{
         "SubAccessCode":{
            "PrimaryIdentity":"763500001"
         }
      },
      "RechargeInfo":{
         "CashPayment":[
            {
               "Amount":"30"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

For that i just wrote a code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cbs/billingmgt/v1.0/Account/Recharge", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String rechargeRequestResponseMatcher(HttpServletRequest request){
        String json =null;
        try {
             json = String.valueOf(request.getReader());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

So my problem is there is an empty value when i evaluate the value of variable json in debug mode. Why and how to get json Body?

Thanks.

Comment: This gives org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteReader@7b2274ea as the value of json

Comment: That is because the `request.getReader()` call returns a `BufferedReader` instance from where you need to get the request content. You are treating the reader as being the content itself. This question should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040504/how-to-easily-convert-a-bufferedreader-to-a-string